# How can I carry license information between different installations of an app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I was working on windows phone 8.1 (WinRT) application. I wanted to give certain users free redemption codes by which they can get the app for free when inserted from the app. But I wanted to change their license info so that even if they

1. Change the device and install the App or
2. Uninstall the App and reinstall it,

they should be able to use the App for free. By using the device ID I can take care of problem 2). But since `LicenseInformation.IsTrial` is a read only property I cant change it and solve problem 1). 
Is there anyway I can at least get the outlook,live ID from which the user has logged in the phone so I can treat it uniquely?

Comment: i don't think your question title reflects the core of the issue. people will read it and initially think it's a question about flipping a boolean.

Comment: How can I rephrase it any suggestions?

Comment: something among the line of 'how can i carry license information between different installations of an app?' or the like

Comment: (downvote is not mine btw)

Comment: @TimothyGroote : Thanks for the help in rephrasing the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create an in-app purchase item with zero price. So when the user enters the code, then make him buy that item for $0. Once bought, it will be associated with his account, and be transferable across devices

Comment: Also make sure it is Durable. or you can set an expiry date on it.